# Iterate through each row of DataFrame using iterrows and next functions in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would write a code which iterate through each row of DataFrame using iterrows and next functions in Python, here's source code :

```
import pandas as pd

#load data frame from csv file
fd = pd.read_csv('Pokemon.csv')

# iterate through each row 
for _ in range(5):
    _, row = next(df.iterrows())
    print(row)
```

but when we run the code, it displays just the first row five times, what is the problem ? because df.iterrows() is an iterator. but when change the loop like this :

```
# iterate through each row 
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

it displays first five rows of data, then why using next function with iterrows method in the loop, it only displays the first row five times instead of showing the first five rows of data ?

....................

Comment: What are you really trying to do? `iterrows` should almost never be used in pandas, it's most often not the correct way to perform computation. Please provide a reproducible example dataset, explain the logic, and provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Lets forget `df.iterrows()` for a moment. What do you think this code below print?

```
for _ in range(5):
    v = next(iter(range(6)))
    print(v)
```

Yes it will print `0` 5 times.

It will create a new iterator each time it runs through the loop, so `next` operates on a new iterator object and gives just the first value.

Also that's not the way `df.iterroows()` is used, and in most cases as the comment by mozway suggests you don't have to use the `iterrows()` unless you have explored vectorized ways and then `apply` and if even that doesn't work, then use `iterrows()`.

Comment: thank you very much, what is other ways to iterrate through dataframe ?

Comment: By other ways I mean non-iterative. pandas supports vectorized operations. I updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In the first bit of code, when you are using the next function, you are calling 'next(df.iterrows())' inside of the loop which creates a new iterator each time it runs, which starts at 0. Therefore, it is printing the first index of your dataframe each time.

The second code works as you have used 'df.iterrows()' outside of the loop (in the declaration), so that is why it runs correctly.

Respect for the pokemon dataframe BTW

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling df.iterrows() in each loop:

to use it properly:

```py
import pandas as pd

#load data frame from csv file
fd = pd.read_csv('Pokemon.csv')

# iterate through each row 
df_iterator = df.iterrows()
for _ in range(5):
    _, row = next(df_iterator)
    print(row)
```

But the nicer way is to do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

#load data frame from csv file
fd = pd.read_csv('Pokemon.csv')

# iterate through each row 
for i, (_, row) = enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 5:
        break;
    print(row)
```